# Elasticsearch index is taking up too much disk space

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have index in production with 1 replica (this takes total ~ 1TB). Into this index every time coming new data (a lot of updates and creates).
When i have created the copy of this index - by running `_reindex`(with the same data and 1 replica as well) - the new index takes 600 GB.
Looks like there is a lot of junk and some kind of logs in original index which possible to cleanup. But not sure how to do it.

The questions: how to cleanup the index (without `_reindex`), why this is happening and how to prevent for it in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Lucene segment files are immutable so when you delete or update (since it can't update doc in place) a document, old version is just marked `deleted` but not actually removed from disk. ES runs `merge` operation periodically to "defragment" the data but you can also trigger merge manually with [_forcemerge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) (try running with `only_expunge_deletes` as well: it might be faster).

Also, make sure your shards [are sized correctly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html) and use [ILM rollover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-rollover.html) to keep index size under control.